# Count distinct values using elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, facet

I am learning elastic search and would like to count distinct values. So far I can count values but not distinct.

Here is the sample data:

```
curl http://localhost:9200/store/item/ -XPOST -d '{
  "RestaurantId": 2,
  "RestaurantName": "Restaurant Brian",
  "DateTime": "2013-08-16T15:13:47.4833748+01:00"
}'

curl http://localhost:9200/store/item/ -XPOST -d '{
  "RestaurantId": 1,
  "RestaurantName": "Restaurant Cecil",
  "DateTime": "2013-08-16T15:13:47.4833748+01:00"
}'

curl http://localhost:9200/store/item/ -XPOST -d '{
  "RestaurantId": 1,
  "RestaurantName": "Restaurant Cecil",
  "DateTime": "2013-08-16T15:13:47.4833748+01:00"
}'
```

And what I tried so far:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/store/item/_search" -d '{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "item": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "RestaurantName"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Output:

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "item": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "restaurant",
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "cecil",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "brian",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get count of `cecil` as 1 instead of 2

Answer (score 14):

You have to use cardinality option as mentioned by [@coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/515068/coder) that you can find in the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html)

```
$ curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/store/item/_search" -d'
{
"aggs" : {
    "restaurant_count" : {
        "cardinality" : {
            "field" : "RestaurantName",
            "precision_threshold": 100, 
            "rehash": false 
            }
          }
         }
}'
```

This worked for me ...

Comment: As correctly pointed by @c24b, `cardinality` serves the purpose here, but I would like to point out a few things here:
1. `cardinality` aggregation is an "approximate" algorithm based on [HyperLogLog++ (HLL)][http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/40671.pdf] algorithm. Quoting from documentation: 
`HLL works by hashing your input and using the bits from the hash to make probabilistic estimations on the cardinality`. There is a trade-off between "precision" and "memory".

Comment: For more details read here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/cardinality.html
My apologies for citing the link as I was not able to explain more due to space constraints.

Comment: Got this error with rehash option: `[7:23] [cardinality] rehash doesn't support values of type: VALUE_BOOLEAN`

Answer (score 5):

Use could use cardinality here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html

Comment: I even tried : curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/store/item/_search" -d' {"size":0,"aggs":{"item":{"cardinality":{"field":"RestaurantName" } }  } }' but not getting distinct counts

Comment: Should be curl -XGET?

Comment: and is it ok to rename the aggregate as item?

Answer (score 4):

It is too late for me to answer this question for the original Author, but for anybody who is facing the same issue and reached here, my answer might help.

ES provides Cardinality for sure to get distinct count, but it is not accurate. For accuracy, a proper solution can be used. I have written an article on this which might help :  [Accurate Distinct Count and Values from Elasticsearch](https://pratik-patil.medium.com/accurate-distinct-count-and-values-from-elasticsearch-dadce51ad4a7).

Answer (score 0):

There's no support for distinct counting in ElasticSearch, although non-deterministic counting exists. Use "terms" aggregation and count buckets in result. See [Count distinct on elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885532/count-distinct-on-elastic-search/44501242#44501242)
 question.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cardinality Feature:
Docs : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html

Example :

```
 "aggs": {
                "unquieValues": {
                  "cardinality": {
                    "field": "ourUniqueId.keyword",
                    "precision_threshold": 100
                  }
                }
              }
```