# Count distinct on elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

How to achieve count distinct function on elastic search type using sql4es driver?

```
Select distinct inv_number , count(1) from invoices;
```

But it returns the total count of the particular invoice number.

Answer (score 13):

```
  {
      "size": 0, 
      "aggs": {
        "total_invoices": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "inv_number" 

        },
        "aggs": {
          "unique_invoiceid": {
            "cardinality": {
              "field": "inv_number"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This will give you the invoice number as **key** and distict value in **unique_invoiceid**

Answer (score 7):

Elasticsearch doesn't support deterministic DISTINCT counts ([source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15876)). It supports only approximate distinct counters like ["cardinality"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html).
One way to count distincts in a deterministic way is to aggregate them using "terms" and count buckets from result.

Comment: Can you share the snippet for counting the number of buckets ?

Answer (score 4):

Since, the OP is using *sql4es jdbc driver*, he is asking for a sql query for his use-case :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT inv_number) from invoices;
```

it returns the number of distinct values of the specified column

Comment: This worked for me in Kibana as an ESQL statement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work to count exact distinct values:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/invoices/_search?size=0&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
"aggs" : {
    "types_count" : {
      "value_count" : { "field" : "inv_number" }
    },
    "group_by_status": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "inv_number"
      }
    }
}
```

}'

Comment: It does not count "distinct" values.

Answer (score 0):

Cardinality works if your dataset uniqueness/fragmentation is less than 2000.
If you really care for accuracy instead of retrieval speed and memory utilization then you can go for scripted metric which will give you accurate results.

https://pratik-patil.medium.com/accurate-distinct-count-and-values-from-elasticsearch-dadce51ad4a7

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).