# Elasticsearch not showing correct data for SQL api

Tags: elasticsearch

es version : 6.7

Hello i'm using elasticsearch sql api 
i found that results not correct when i add DISTINCT

es code

```
require('./elasticsearch/').transport.request({
        method : "POST",
        path   : '/_xpack/sql',
        body : {
            query : "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)  FROM orders"
        }  
    },(err,res) => {
        console.log("error",err)
        return res.status(200).send(res)
    })
```

results :

```
{
   "columns":[{"name":"COUNT(DISTINCT id)","type":"long"}],
    "rows":[[11459]] <----------------------------------------------- MUST BE (11501)
}
```

i execute same query in mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)  FROM orders
```

results

```
11501
```

Any Helps ?
Thank you

Comment: I believe this answer may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44501242/5095957

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to ES member

COUNT(DISTINCT) from SQL is using a cardinality aggregation behind the scene which, by design, **doesn't offer accurate results** in all scenarios:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/50354

So basically you should do it with DSL instead of SQL API