# Elasticsearch why i cant do a accurate distinct on a field?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Try to get a distinct count on an index containing field value more then once. i have differences between the SQL data and the elastic data, why is that?

Comment: Maybe you need to show some sample data, your mapping and the queries you're making... Help us help you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Cardinality Aggreagtion gives a
> count of distinct values. Values can be extracted either from specific
> fields in the document or generated by a script.

Refer this to know more about [Cardinality Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html)

You can even refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885532/count-distinct-on-elastic-search/56482740#:%7E:text=Elasticsearch%20doesn%27t%20support%20deterministic,and%20count%20buckets%20from%20result.) to know more about how to count distinct on elasticsearch

Comment: but i did that and it is not giving me accurate results. in the post they saying that it is an approximate calculation

Comment: @Shahar can you provide some sample data, your mappings and search query which u are using ?

Comment: i cant post all the sample data but i did an simple example of an index containing customer_id which has duplicates records the total for both sql and elastic are 11703. then in the kibana i have created a metric visualization with metric of unique count. in the distinct SQL statement on the same example im getting 6678 records and in the kibana im getting 6671

Answer (score 0):

Accurate Distinct Count can be found from ES. You can refer the article on "[Accurate Distinct Count and Values from Elasticsearch](https://pratik-patil.medium.com/accurate-distinct-count-and-values-from-elasticsearch-dadce51ad4a7)" for complete solution and comparison against Cardinality.